# How do I unlock the mute button on my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

My MacBook won’t play any sound, when clicking the keys it comes up with this symbol underneath . I have looked under system preferences and it is muted but the mute button is a grey colour like it is locked so I can’t untick the box. At the top of my MacBook next to the wifi it has a mute symbol aswell. I think I may have locked myself out of sound but I am unaware of how to unlock it. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Have you tried a reboot? Have you tried a different user account? Have you tried resetting NVRAM/PRAM/SMC?

Comment: What does it list as your output?

Comment: No need to reset anything. Open System Preference-> Sound, and look what is selected as sound output.

Comment: @Ruskes it says there is no output devices found, and next to the output volume the mute button is ticked but it’s also locked so I can’t untick it.

Comment: @Ezekiel is says there is no output devices found.

Comment: @agarza I’ve tried rebooting and restarting, I also don’t have another user account. But I do think it is something along the lines of me locking myself out and a different admin has to unlock it maybe?

Comment: You can [create a new user account](https://support.apple.com/en-jo/guide/mac-help/mtusr001/mac) and check to see if the same problems are happening in **that** account. If it isn't, the problem is a software issue on your user account.

Comment: Plug in a headset

Comment: You issue isn't that the output is muted, it's that there is no output device found. No device… no volume possible. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7502425 for a very good workthrough, too much to précis here.